# Why does using then() callback in ExpressJS after a promise giving me an Error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm new to NodeJS and ExpressJS. I'm trying to execute a simple Database query.

```
db.execute('SELECT * FROM restaurant').then().catch()
```

I'm getting this error :

> db.execute('SELECT * FROM restaurant').then().catch()
>                                         ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

I'm using MySQL Database running on phpMyAdmin. This is my Database Snapshot.

[image]

I've checked my database, it is connected. Below is my code in App.js!

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const admin = require('./routes/admin');
const shop = require('./routes/shop');
const db = require('./config/db');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))

app.use('/admin',admin);
app.use('/shop',shop)

db.execute('SELECT * FROM restaurant').then().catch()

app.get('/', (req,res) =>{
res.status(200).send('<h3>Front page</h3>')
});


app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
res.status(404).send('<h1>File not found</h1>')
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);

console.log('App is listening on port ' + port);
```

I want the names of the restaurant to get display on the browser.

Below is config/db file:

```
var mysql = require('mysql2');
var db = mysql.createPool({
host : 'localhost',
user: 'root',
database:'pos',
password:''
});

module.exports=db
```

Comment: I'd ask the question why does `db.execute('SELECT * FROM restaurant')` return undefined?

Comment: `db.execute` is not a promise. You can use `.then` only on promises. You'll have to do something like `async - await`

Comment: on a side note, `bodyParser` is deprecated, it should give you an error, use `app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))` instead

Comment: async await is a syntax to work on promises... his `db.execute` is returning undefined as the error says.

Comment: Also try to share the content of `config/db` file .... because this error it means that this is not promise in the first place....so it will be helpful to see what you are passing `'SELECT * FROM restaurant'` to

Comment: @Ahm. Okay I'm attaching the     config/db file too.

Comment: try to find an `execute`-like function that returns a Promise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to export the promisified version of your pool in your config file like this:

```
var mysql = require('mysql2');
var db = mysql.createPool({
   host : 'localhost',
   user: 'root',
   database:'pos',
   password:''
});

module.exports=db.promise()
```

For more info, check the [mysql2 docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper).